# React Native Reanimated entering animations does not work

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

My issue here is this callback in entering animation on Animated.View does not work on Android while it works perfectly on IOS. Do you know any possible reasons?

```
const contentHeight = useSharedValue(0);
const sheetRef = useAnimatedRef();
const [modalVisibility, setModalVisibility] = useState<boolean>(false);

const measureSheet = useCallback(() => {
    'worklet';
    const measurement = measure(sheetRef);
    if (measurement === null) {
      return;
    }
    contentHeight.value = measurement.height;
  }, [contentHeight, sheetRef]);

return (
    <Modal transparent visible={modalVisibility}>
      <GestureHandlerRootView style={styles.wrapper}>
        {showBackDrop && (
          <AnimatedPressable
            style={[styles.backDrop, backDropOpacity]}
            entering={FadeIn.duration(300)}
            onPress={onBackDropPress}
          />
        )}

        <GestureDetector gesture={pan}>
          <Animated.View
            ref={sheetRef}
            entering={SlideInDown.duration(300).easing(Easing.out(Easing.exp)).withCallback(measureSheet)} //withCallback does not work
            style={[styles.sheet, sheetExtraStyle, sheetTranslateStyle]}>
            <View style={styles.holder} />
            {children}
          </Animated.View>
        </GestureDetector>
      </GestureHandlerRootView>
    </Modal>
```

React native and reanimated versions

```
   "react-native-reanimated": "^3.5.4",
   "react-native": "0.72.7",
```